# Showing that the metric $d$ is a norm

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a vector space, and $d:X\times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a metric on $X$. Also suppose that $d$ is invariant under translations, i.e. $d(x,y)=d(x+z,y+z)$ for all $x,y,z \in X$. Is $d(x,y)$ for any $x\in X$, and y equal to zero, a norm?

Comment: Think of Hamming metric over $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q \neq 2$. It cannot induce a norm.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. First of all note that if $d$ is a metric induced by a norm then it must satisfy the following two properties

(1) $d(x,y)=d(x+z,y+z)$;

(2) $d(ax,ay)= |a|d(x,y)$

for all scalars $a$ and vectors $x,y,z$.

So, the discrete metric will be a trivial counter example to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Another counterexample on any Banach space $X$: choose
$$d(x,y) = f(\|x - y\|_{X})$$
where $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$

- is monotonically increasing
- $f(x) = 0$ iff $x = 0$
- is subadditive

This is not induced by a norm unless $f$ is linear.